# Bums take over the world

Tags: story-identification, books

I believe it may have been a series so some details may be mixed between the books. I read it maybe 10 years ago.

It starts out with the protagonist waking up in the middle of the night to find his bum missing. He hears some sounds and climbs out of his window and (follows his bum?) to a stadium where a load of bums have come together to have a meeting about taking over the world.

At some point in the story the protagonist leaves Earth to go to Uranus (obviously!) and then comes back to Earth to find it is almost completely taken over by the bums.

I believe they end up stopping the bums from taking over the Earth (doing so by letting out a synchronised fart?).

Any ideas?

---

<sup>By bum I mean one's gluteus maximus</sup>

Comment: A good start, but take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) which may help you add a few more details.

Comment: @Edlothiad How many books can there be about bums taking over the world? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well the series is a trilogy so at least 3 :P

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot You're actually describing the first two books of the series here, or possibly getting them mixed up. The window and stadium are in the first couple of chapters of book 1, but the whole Uranus thing is only in book 2, and is an entirely separate incident of bums trying to take over the world (although with the same mastermind - the Great White Bum - involved in both). The third book involves time travel and is, IMO, by far the worst of the three (cash-in?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well it has been a while since I read them, and I was young, so I'm not surprised I got the details mixed up.

Comment: Ha! I thought the subject was hoboes/tramps/transients till I read the answer.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Or [boxing](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ohwKp4stsPI/UtVrdyJFo4I/AAAAAAAAdGg/0HfShvjbSgc/s1600/OACGBum.gif)

Comment: @OrganicMarble So did I. Or a parallel universe where everyone owns a pet bum.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Until I read the clarifying remark at the bottom, going to Uranus was not obvious to me at all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is almost certainly

## [The Day My Bum Went Psycho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Day_My_Bum_Went_Psycho) by Andy Griffiths

Wikipedia's plot summary gives some insight into the details:

> Zack Freeman's bum is constantly detaching itself from his body and running off. One night, when he follows his bum, he learns that there is a plot by bums to take over the world.

The worldwide fart was actually the bums' plan to destroy the world:

> Specifically, the bums plan to create a huge, worldwide fart by building up a massive quantity of methane gas in the "Bumcano".

The story is part of a trilogy called the [Bum trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bum_trilogy):

The final two books are titled [Zombie Bums from Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_Bums_from_Uranus) and [Bumageddon: The Final Pongflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumageddon:_The_Final_Pongflict)

There was also an Australian TV show [by the same name](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4363582/)

Covers below because there's butts.

> [image: Cover 1][image: Cover 2][image: Cover 3]

Comment: I thought the premise sounded pretty ridiculous, but then I find out it was based on a true story, so I guess I have no cause to complain.

Comment: I notice only books one and three are based on a true story... :)

Comment: @Chris it would appear this would need remedying

Comment: Considering this is a HNQ, maybe a spoiler for the cover art? I'm pretty sure that someone somewhere may be talking to HR right now about showing bums on their screen at work.

Comment: @phyrfox you go it. Although if you're on SFF is the most obvious site where you're not doing work, one always needs to be sneaky when they're on here.

Comment: @Chris - come on, man, _zombie_ buns?  Get real.

Comment: "There was also an Australian TV show by the same name" ...Of course there was.

Comment: Apparently the TV show was an Australian/Canadian collaboration. Which makes even more sense. I expect it featured Paul Hogan, Steve Irwin, and Terence and Phillip...

Comment: I was rather disappointed to learn this was not a Chuck Tingle book...